# Assign mesh to physical group in gmsh

Tags: mesh

I am trying to explicitly assign the mesh data to a physical group so it can be saved to a mesh file along with the other groups that have geometrical data. I know you use the

```
gmsh::option::setNumber("Mesh.SaveAll", 1);
```

But I need to use the old format which actually destroys all the physicalgroup information after the save. I am hoping there is a way around this.

Thanks in advance